# Apache POI printing of line shapes problem

Tags: java, apache-poi

I need your help, I have a code ( See below ) that add line shapes with arrows in a cell in excel using Apache POI in Java. See my code. but after exporting, then opening the excel this message from dialog throws, "Drawing from /xl/drawings/drawing3.xml part (Drawing shape)". Please see screenshot.

```java
// create workbook
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet( "Node" );
CreationHelper helper = wb.getCreationHelper();
Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();

//anchor from
//parent
anchor.setCol1( gParentCell.getColumnIndex() + 1 );
anchor.setRow1( gParentCell.getRowIndex() );

anchor.setDy1( Units.toEMU( 7.2 ) );

//anchor to
//child
anchor.setCol2( this.col );
anchor.setRow2( this.row );

anchor.setDy2( Units.toEMU( 7.2 ) );

XSSFSimpleShape shape = ((XSSFDrawing)drawing).createSimpleShape((XSSFClientAnchor)anchor);
shape.setShapeType( ShapeTypes.LINE );
shape.setLineWidth(1);
shape.setLineStyle(0);

// draw the arrow
CTShapeProperties shapeProperties = shape.getCTShape().getSpPr();

CTLineEndProperties lineEndProperties = org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTLineEndProperties.Factory.newInstance();
lineEndProperties.setType(STLineEndType.TRIANGLE);

// print arrow
CTLineProperties lineProperties = shapeProperties.getLn();
lineProperties.setTailEnd(lineEndProperties);
```

[Excel is trying to recover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdzqG.png)

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uu6vv.png)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8mYk.png)

Comment: This code is incomplete. So the problem cannot be reproduced. Debugging hint: In an anchor the index of col1 always needs to be lower than col2 and the index of row1 needs to be lower than row2. So check `gParentCell.getColumnIndex() + 1` vs. `this.col` and `gParentCell.getRowIndex()` vs. `this.row`.

Comment: thanks @AxelRichter for your explanation. I'll try to check on the logs the values.

Comment: @AxelRichter Ithink this triggered the problem, "index of row1 needs to be lower than row2". How can I prevent it? since I need to draw a line like for example 

col1 = 0
row1 = 5

col2 = 3
row2 = 2

Comment: The anchor must be col1 = 0, row1 = 2, col2 = 3, row2 = 5. Drawn lines in anchors are always top left to bottom right. But if needed you can flip them vertically: `shape.getCTShape().getSpPr().getXfrm().setFlipV(true);`

Comment: @AxelRichter you got it right. the line draws perfectly but still getting the error of "Repair Records".

Comment: Repaired Records: Drawing from /xl/drawings/drawing1.xml part (Drawing shape)

Comment: I gave you a complete working example in my answer. As said since your code is incomplete, the problem cannot be reproduced.

Answer (score 1):

In an anchor the index of `col1` always needs to be lower than the one of `col2` and the index of `row1` needs to be lower than the one of `row2`. Drawn lines in anchors are always top left to bottom right. If needed you can flip them vertically.

So if the need is drawing a line from `B14` to `G4` for example, you create an anchor `B4:G14`, draw the line and then flip the shape vertically.

```
shape.getCTShape().getSpPr().getXfrm().setFlipV(true);
```

Complete example:

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.ShapeTypes;
import org.apache.poi.util.Units;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.*;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

class CreateExcelLineShapesArrows {

 static XSSFSimpleShape drawLine(XSSFCell fromCell, XSSFCell toCell) {
  XSSFWorkbook wb = fromCell.getSheet().getWorkbook();
  XSSFCreationHelper helper = wb.getCreationHelper();
  XSSFSheet sheet = fromCell.getSheet();
  XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
  XSSFClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();

  int fromCol = Math.min(fromCell.getColumnIndex(), toCell.getColumnIndex());
  int toCol = Math.max(fromCell.getColumnIndex(), toCell.getColumnIndex());
  int fromRow = Math.min(fromCell.getRow().getRowNum(), toCell.getRow().getRowNum());
  int toRow = Math.max(fromCell.getRow().getRowNum(), toCell.getRow().getRowNum());

  anchor.setCol1(fromCol);
  anchor.setRow1(fromRow); // anchor starts top left of this cell
  anchor.setDy1(Units.toEMU(sheet.getRow(fromRow).getHeightInPoints()/2)); //plus 1/2 row height
  anchor.setCol2(toCol);
  anchor.setRow2(toRow);// anchor ends top left of this cell
  anchor.setDy2(Units.toEMU(sheet.getRow(toRow).getHeightInPoints()/2)); //plus 1/2 row height

  XSSFSimpleShape shape = drawing.createSimpleShape(anchor);
  shape.setShapeType(ShapeTypes.LINE);
  shape.setLineWidth(1);
  shape.setLineStyleColor(0, 0, 0);

  if (fromCell.getRow().getRowNum() > toCell.getRow().getRowNum()) { // if fromCell's row is below toCells's row, then flip vertically
   shape.getCTShape().getSpPr().getXfrm().setFlipV(true);
  }

  return shape;
 }

 static void setTailEndTriangle(XSSFSimpleShape shape) {
  CTShapeProperties shapeProperties = shape.getCTShape().getSpPr();
  CTLineProperties lineProperties = shapeProperties.getLn();
  CTLineEndProperties lineEndProperties = CTLineEndProperties.Factory.newInstance();
  lineEndProperties.setType(STLineEndType.TRIANGLE);
  //lineEndProperties.setLen(STLineEndLength.LG);
  //lineEndProperties.setW(STLineEndWidth.LG);
  lineProperties.setTailEnd(lineEndProperties);
 }

 static void setHeadEndTriangle(XSSFSimpleShape shape) {
  CTShapeProperties shapeProperties = shape.getCTShape().getSpPr();
  CTLineProperties lineProperties = shapeProperties.getLn();
  CTLineEndProperties lineEndProperties = CTLineEndProperties.Factory.newInstance();
  lineEndProperties.setType(STLineEndType.TRIANGLE);
  //lineEndProperties.setLen(STLineEndLength.LG);
  //lineEndProperties.setW(STLineEndWidth.LG);
  lineProperties.setHeadEnd(lineEndProperties);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

  XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();

  XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Sheet1");

  XSSFCell cellG4 = sheet.createRow(3).createCell(6); cellG4.setCellValue("Test A");
  XSSFCell cellA14 = sheet.createRow(13).createCell(0); cellA14.setCellValue("Test");
  XSSFCell cellB14 = sheet.getRow(13).createCell(1);
  XSSFCell cellG23 = sheet.createRow(22).createCell(6); cellG23.setCellValue("Test B");

  XSSFSimpleShape shape = drawLine(cellB14, cellG23);
  setTailEndTriangle(shape);
  shape = drawLine(cellB14, cellG4);
  setTailEndTriangle(shape);

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateExcelLineShapesArrows.xlsx");
  wb.write(out);
  out.close();
  wb.close();

 }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I want to share also what I learned just now,

This is correct shape.getCTShape().getSpPr().getXfrm().setFlipV(true);

But you can also use ShapeTypes.LINE_INV;

Comment: There is a difference. If you select the line shape in `Excel`, then a default line, even if flipped, is selected as a line, while a lineInv is selected as rectangle shape having the anchor's dimensions.